# jquery - How to validate this Time format '3:00 PM'

Tags: jquery

I have a `var = time` whose value is `'3:00 PM'` and an `<input type='time'`

here when user selects/entered time then i need to make sure that its greater than `var = time`

here is my complete code:

```
<input type='time' id='new_time' >

<script>
var time = '3:00 PM';

if($("#new_time").val() < time )
{
     alert("not allowed");
}
else
{
     alert("allowed");
}
</script>
```

any suggestion please to achieve this in correct way

Comment: 24 hour format or 12 hour format ?? @arsee

Comment: any problem with converting to 24 hour behind the scenes?

Comment: @surajrawat its 12 hour format

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs actually it will be great if we can make it in 12 hr format, 24 hr format is easily we can validate

Comment: @Arsee I more mean, there wouldn't be a downside to comparing in 24 hour in your code and displaying in 12 hour using the date object native to... I think JS but it could be jQuery, either way, it's not too hard to convert formats back and forth :)

Comment: input type date is a 24 hour format

Comment: any best approach will be appreciated

Comment: @surajrawat yes its 24 hr, but the result i am getting is in 12 hr format, so any best way to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

**[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)**

Moment.js is a lightweight library then helps us to parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates and times in JavaScript.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<script>    
   var time = moment('3:00pm', 'h:mma');
   var newTime = moment($("#new_time").val(), 'h:mma');
   console.log(time.isBefore(newTime)); // true
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTime").value;
    alert(x);
    var time = '3:00 PM';
var time1 = x;
if(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+time1) > Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+time))
    {
        alert("End time should exceed the start time");
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

Time: <input type="time" id="myTime" value="16:32:55"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```